# How to return a String representation of a 2D array without the Array-class?

Tags: java, arrays, string, return

i have this assignment that i am struggeling with:
Implement a method: public static String tilStreng(int[][] matrise)
that returns a string representation of an 2d array.
the array is as following: { {1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9} }
The returned string shall contain: 1 2 3 \n4 5 6 \n7 8 9 \n

i am completly lost, but this is what i have been doing until now:

```java
public class OppgaveB {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[][] tall = "";
        
        tilStreng(matrise);
    }

    public static String tilStreng(int[][] matrise) {

        for (int i = 0; i < matrise.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; (matrise[i] != null && j < matrise[i].length); j++) {
                
                tall = tall + matrise [i][j] + " " ;
                tall = tall + " \n";
            }

            System.out.println();

        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: The code provided won't pass the compile checks, you should create a proper 2d int array and pass it to your `tilStreng` so you can at least test it.

Answer (score 0):

- Your task is to return string representation from `tilStreng` but your method returns null
- You should pass 2d int array not string for example
  `int[][] matrise = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};`
- after you call `tilStreng` you should save the return value and print it
- Check this article to learn how to print 2d array https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-2-d-array-matrix-java/

```java
public static String tilStreng(int[][] matrise) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < matrise.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0 ; j < matrise[i].length ; j++) {
            builder.append(matrise[i][j]).append(" ");
        }
        builder.append("\n");
    }
    return builder.toString();
}

public static void main(String... args) {
    int[][] matrise = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
    String representation = tilStreng(matrise);
    System.out.println(representation);
}
```